# How do I update a Map with BLoC and equatable?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am still a beginner with BLoC architecture. So far the UI updates when using int, bool, and other basic data types. But when it comes to Maps it really confuses me. My code basically looks like this:

my state

```
enum TalentStatus { initial, loading, loaded, error }

class TalentState extends Equatable {
  const TalentState({
    required this.talentStatus,
    this.selectedService = const {},
    required this.talents,
    this.test = 0,
  });

  final TalentStatus talentStatus;
  final Talents talents;
  final Map<String, Service> selectedService;
  final int test;

  TalentState copyWith({
    TalentStatus? talentStatus,
    Talents? talents,
    Map<String, Service>? selectedService,
    int? test,
  }) =>
      TalentState(
        selectedService: selectedService ?? this.selectedService,
        talentStatus: talentStatus ?? this.talentStatus,
        talents: talents ?? this.talents,
        test: test ?? this.test,
      );

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [talentStatus, talents, selectedService, test];
}
```

my event

```
abstract class TalentEvent extends Equatable {
  const TalentEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class TalentStarted extends TalentEvent {}

class TalentSelectService extends TalentEvent {
  const TalentSelectService(
    this.service,
    this.talentName,
  );

  final Service service;
  final String talentName;
}
```

and my bloc

```
class TalentBloc extends Bloc<TalentEvent, TalentState> {
  TalentBloc(this._talentRepository)
      : super(TalentState(
            talentStatus: TalentStatus.initial, talents: Talents())) {
    on<TalentSelectService>(_selectService);
  }

  final TalentRepository _talentRepository;

  Future<void> _selectService(
    TalentSelectService event,
    Emitter<TalentState> emit,
  ) async {
    state.selectedService[event.talentName] = event.service;
    final selectedService = Map<String, Service>.of(state.selectedService);

    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        selectedService: selectedService,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

whenever an event **TalentSelectService** is called BlocBuilder doesn't trigger, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Service` object must be comparable. One suggestion is that it extends `Equatable`. Either way it have to implement (override) the `==` operator and `hashCode`

The reason your BlocBuilder doesn't trigger is (probably) that it doesn't recognize that there has been a change in the Map.